# Random access over all pair-wise combinations of large list in Python

Tags: python, list, combinations, combinatorics, large-data

**Background:**

I have a list of 44906 items: `large = [1, 60, 17, ...]`. I also have a personal computer with limited memory (8GB), running Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

**The Goal:**

I need to find all the pair-wise combinations of `large` in a memory-efficient manner, without filling a list with all the combinations beforehand.

**The Problem & What I've Tried So Far:**

When I use `itertools.combinations(large, 2)`, and try to assign it to a list my memory fills up immediately, and I get very slow performance. The reason for this is that the number of pairwise combinations goes like `n*(n-1)/2` where `n` is the number of elements of the list.

The number of combinations for `n=44906` comes out to `44906*44905/2 = 1008251965`. A list with this many entries is much too large to store in memory. I would like to be able to design a function so that I can plug in a number `i` to find the `i`th pair-wise combination of numbers in this list, and a way to somehow dynamically compute this combination, without referring to a 1008251965 element list that's impossible to store in memory.

**An Example of What I Am Trying To Do:**

Let's say I have an array `small = [1,2,3,4,5]`

In the configuration in which I have the code, `itertools.combinations(small, 2)` will return a list of tuples as such:

```
[(1, 2), # 1st entry
 (1, 3), # 2nd entry
 (1, 4), # 3rd entry
 (1, 5), # 4th entry
 (2, 3), # 5th entry
 (2, 4), # 6th entry 
 (2, 5), # 7th entry
 (3, 4), # 8th entry
 (3, 5), # 9th entry
 (4, 5)] # 10th entry
```

A call to a the function like this: `find_pair(10)' would return:

```
(4, 5)
```

, giving the 10th entry in the would-be array, but without calculating the entire combinatorial explosion beforehand.

The thing is, I need to be able to drop in to the middle of the combinations, not starting from the beginning every time, which is what it seems like an iterator does:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> it = combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)
>>> next(it)
(1, 2)
>>> next(it)
(1, 3)
>>> next(it)
(1, 4)
>>> next(it)
(1, 5)
```

So, instead of having to execute next() 10 times to get to the 10th combination, I would like to be able to retrieve the tuple returned by the 10th iteration with one call.

**The Question**

Are there any other combinatorial functions that behave this way designed to deal with huge data sets? If not, is there a good way to implement a memory-saving algorithm that behaves this way?

Comment: Would a binary file fit your needs?  You can index it with the <file>.seek(<position>) command.

Comment: Could you explain your suggestion further?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you need to do with your combinations. Your title suggests you want to iterate over them, for which the iterator returned from `itertools.combinations` seems ideal (just don't turn it into a list!). The body of your question however seems to need random access to the combinations in some unclear way. If you're going to iterate, you don't need random access. If you do need random access, you can probably come up with a way of translating your combination-index into a pair of indexes into the original list.

Comment: Definitely a case of XY problem going on here. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I will edit the question to make it very clear what exactly I am trying to do.

Comment: @Prune, when you get a chance, could you elaborate on your binary file idea, possibly with an answer?

Comment: Sure -- although the answer I posted is faster and uses less memory.  ///  Use the **itertools** generator and write the pairs directly to a file; use binary format so that each integer takes the same amount of space (4 bytes each, 8 bytes per pair).  Open your binary file as, say, **pair_file**.  When you want pair **N** from the set, do **pair_file.seek(8*N)** and then read two integers from that spot.

Comment: @Prune, would it be a problem that some of my numbers are as large as 40,000 storing them in a binary file as you have specified?

Comment: @jackskis, that's no problem at all.  The basic integer is much larger than that (32 or 64 bits).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want random access to any combination you can use this function to return the index of a corresponding lower triangular  representation of the cross-product

```
def comb(k):         
        row=int((math.sqrt(1+8*k)+1)/2)    
        column=int(k-(row-1)*(row)/2)  
        return [row,column]
```

using your small array for example

```
small = [1,2,3,4,5]
length = len(small)
size = int(length * (length-1)/2)
for i in range(size):
    [n,m] = comb(i)
    print(i,[n,m],"(",small[n],",",small[m],")")
```

will give

```
0 [1, 0] ( 2 , 1 )
1 [2, 0] ( 3 , 1 )
2 [2, 1] ( 3 , 2 )
3 [3, 0] ( 4 , 1 )
4 [3, 1] ( 4 , 2 )
5 [3, 2] ( 4 , 3 )
6 [4, 0] ( 5 , 1 )
7 [4, 1] ( 5 , 2 )
8 [4, 2] ( 5 , 3 )
9 [4, 3] ( 5 , 4 )
```

obviously if your access method is in order other methods will be more practical.

Note also that the `comb` function is independent of the size of the problem.

As suggested by @Blckknght in the comments to get the same order as itertools version change to

```
for i in range(size):
        [n,m] = comb(size-1-i) 
        print(i,[n,m],"(",small[length-1-n],",",small[length-1-m],")")  


0 [4, 3] ( 1 , 2 )
1 [4, 2] ( 1 , 3 )
2 [4, 1] ( 1 , 4 )
3 [4, 0] ( 1 , 5 )
4 [3, 2] ( 2 , 3 )
5 [3, 1] ( 2 , 4 )
6 [3, 0] ( 2 , 5 )
7 [2, 1] ( 3 , 4 )
8 [2, 0] ( 3 , 5 )
9 [1, 0] ( 4 , 5 )
```

Comment: Note that it's really a bit trickier than this (see your `6 [3, 3] ( 4, 4 )` output for why).

Comment: Yes, and this solution doesn't behave as 'itertools.combinations()' does

Comment: thanks for the feedback, fixed the triangular mapping now.

Comment: To fix the ordering, you need to count from the end of ordering and invert the indexes. Use `n, m = comb(size - 1 - i)` and then `small[length - 1 - n]` and `small[length - 1 - m]`

Comment: Also, changing the generator to upper triangular version will do it, but it needs then to know the size.  Your suggestion is better.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @karakfa, do you have any references for the formula you use for comb() above?

Comment: No, I came up with this, but I'm sure I'm not the first one. I'll write something up.  It's essentially inverse of enumerating lower triangular section of a matrix.  The formula is the root of quadratic equation `x^2-x-2k` arising from `x*(x-1)/2` as the triangular number when solving for the lower bound.

Comment: here is a reference on SE.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455511/formula-for-the-nth-term-of-1-2-2-3-3-3-4-4-4-4-5

Answer (score 6):

Except `itertools.combinations` does not return a list - it returns an iterator.  Here:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> it = combinations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)
>>> next(it)
(1, 2)
>>> next(it)
(1, 3)
>>> next(it)
(1, 4)
>>> next(it)
(1, 5)
>>> next(it)
(2, 3)
>>> next(it)
(2, 4)
```

and so on.  It's extremely memory-efficient:  only one pair is produced per invocation.

Of course it *is* possible to write a function that returns the `n'th` result, but before bothering with that (which will be slower and more involved), are you quite sure you can't just use `combinations()` the way it was *designed* to be used (i.e., iterating over it, instead of forcing it to produce a giant list)?

Comment: I edited the question to more refine what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks!  If you want "random access" in constant time, then you'll need to write your own code for that.  @Captain already sketched a start; I'd flesh it out, but can't make time now.  I bet someone else can, though ;-)

Comment: Yes, I am just wondering if there are some pre written libraries I can take advantage of! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here's the math needed:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#Finding_the_k-combination_for_a_given_number

Comment: It wont be in constant time but you can use islice like this: `itertools.islice(it, 5, 7)` so it will contain 6th and 7th elements.

Answer (score 3):

I started with that triangular arrangement, finding the subscript **k** for list members indexed **row** and **col**.  Then I reversed the process, deriving **row** and **col** from **k**.

For a list **large** of **N** items, let

```
b = 2*N - 1
```

Now, to get the **k**th combination in the list ...

```
row = (b - math.sqrt(b*b - 8*k)) // 2
col = k - (2*N - row + 1)*row / 2
kth_pair = large[row][col]
```

This allows you to access any member of the combinations list without ever generating that list.

Answer (score 1):

So you've got 44906 items. Notice, however, that if you build your combinations the same way you build them in the example then there are 44905 combinations with `large[0]` as the first number. Furthermore, combination `i` for `i <= 44905` looks like `(large[0], large[i])`.

For `44905 < i <= 89809`, it looks like `(large[1],large[i-44904])`.

If I'm not mistaken, this pattern should continue with something like `(large[j],large[i-(exclusive lower bound for j)+1])`. You can check my math on that but I'm pretty sure it's right. Anyways, you could iterate to find these lower bounds (so for j=0, it's 0, for j=1, it's 44905, etc.) Iterating should be easy because you just add the next descending number: 44905, 44905+44904, 44905+44904+44903...

Answer (score 1):

For well defined order of created pairs, indices of first and second elements should be related to n and length of a sequence. If you'll find them, you'll be able to achieve const-time performance, since indexing lists is `O(1)` operation.

Pseudocode would look like this:

```
def find_nth_pair(seq, n):
    idx1 = f1(n, len(seq))  # some formula of n and len(seq)
    idx2 = f2(n, len(seq))  # some formula of n and len(seq)
    return (seq[idx1], seq[idx2])
```

You only need to find formulas for idx1 and idx2.